# Convert byte array to Image

Tags: java, arrays, image, byte

I have a byte array which size is 640*480*3 and its byte order is r,g,b. I'm trying to convert it into Image. The following code doesn't work:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

with the excepton

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:925)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
```

I also tried this code:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(data);
Image img = imageIcon.getImage();
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR); //Exception
```

but unsuccessfully:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) must be > 0
```

How can I receive the Image from this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plain byte array is not a gnerally recognized image format. You have to code the conversion yourself. Luckily its not very hard to do:

```
int w = 640;
int h = 480;
BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
for (int y=0; y<h; ++y) {
    for (int x=0; x<w; ++x) {
        // calculate index of pixel
        // depends on exact organization of image
        // sample assumes linear storage with r, g, b pixel order
        int index = (y * w * 3) + (x * 3);
        // combine to RGB format
        int rgb = ((data[index++] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                  ((data[index++] & 0xFF) <<  8) |
                  ((data[index++] & 0xFF)      ) |
                  0xFF000000;
        i.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
    }
}
```

The exact formula for pixel index depends on how you organized the data in the array - which you didn't really specify precisely. The prinicple is always the same though, combine the R, G, B value into an RGB (ARGB to be precise) value and put it in the BufferedImage using setRGB() method.

Comment: `A plain byte array is not a gnerally recognized image format. ` what is the source of this info and why it would be that ? And the second case actually reveals that he is having issue with the image itself,  he intends to read

Comment: @Sage The source for the info is *common sense*. Something not specified can't be a generally recognized image format, or can it? There is a gazillion ways to transform an image into a byte[] (and the OP described it briefly 640*480*3 - that leaves no space for *any* meta data, so it can't be a generic format). At least that much is  obvious to *me*. And the trouble "reading" the image is a natural result of the format not being recognized. All the exceptions result directly or indirectly from an unrecognizable image format. Take a look at the Javadocs for IconImage.

Comment: thank you i missed the `640*480*3 ` mentioning. Actually His second exception got me distracted and confused me.